# Can't get text area contents enclosed in <...> in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a form with a textarea in an HTML page and I'm trying to send its contents to a servlet via POST. The problem is that if I write something like `unenclosed <enclosed>` in the textarea, when I call `request.getParameter("textareaId")` (where *request* is a *HttpServletRequest* object) in the *service()* method of the servlet (that extends *HttpServlet*), I get only "unenclosed" as parameter value. Is there any way to get the complete contents of the textarea?

Html code:

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="post">
    <textarea name="MyTextarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

Servlet code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String contents = request.getParameter("MyTextarea");
        System.out.println(contents);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I solved it by escaping the textarea contents in a JavaScript function before sending it to the servlet.

Comment: Can you post your HTML page, your servlet code and let us know if you are using any other kind of web framework code?

Comment: Edited. I don't use any special framework.

Answer (score 1):

This `index.jsp` works for me on Tomcat 6.0.35. I see the `<` and `>` printed to the console.

```
<%
    String contents = request.getParameter("MyTextarea");
    System.out.println(contents);
%>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="MyTextarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

What servlet container are you using?

Does the container have any parameter escaping turned on by default?

What is the default character encoding (can't really see that being an issue as `<` and `>` are regular ASCII)?

Comment: I am using Resin, but I'm not sure about the settings and char encoding. Anyway, I solved it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `<textarea name="MyTextarea">...</textarea>` one should use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
This can be done with apache common's **EscapeUtils.escapeHTML** (I think). This also holds for `<input value="...">` or in `<a href="... .jsp?a=1&amp;b=2">`: `&amp; &lt; &gt; &quot; &apos;`.

Comment: I think the question is regarding data coming from the page to the servlet. In this case, a user wouldn't type `&lt;` or `&gt;` in the textarea.

Comment: If the user enters `<` that should be given back by `request.getParameter`, but on outputing to HTML it should be converted to `&lt;`.

Comment: If I put only < or >, it works fine, but if I put < ... >, it is removed, maybe it thinks that it is a tag or something...

Comment: Yes, try `<b>xxx</b>`. Inside `<p>` that would be HTML, inside `<textarea>` should be lt/gt entities.