# How to get value of a html textarea (given its id/name) using Java?

Tags: java, html

I have a html page with several tags.
I need to get the value of the tag textarea. For eg

I have several lines of data inside textarea tag.
I need to get its value using JAVA. Can somebody give suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: using request.getParameter("filedname"), check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149347/cant-get-text-area-contents-enclosed-in-in-servlet

Comment: You are writing a servlet?

Answer (score 1):

You can access it in  servlet using it's name.

```
String textAreaValue = request.getParameter("TextAreaName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with html & Java Script. Here is the code

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function getData() {
           var textarea = document.getElementsByName("textareaname");
           alert(textarea[0].value);
        }
    </script>
    <body>
       <textarea  name="textareaname" class="siva"></textarea>
       <a href="javascript:getData()">getdata</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My Java code has a string. I need to call the java script function with the string that I have.  I need to get the contents of textarea inside the string.